# Overlapping Sidebar List CSS

Tags: css

On the sidebar on this page:
http://www.sandiegolawfirm.com/business/

You can see that on the left sidebar(scroll down) the 3rd level child page list item is overlapping it's parent page list item. I have been attempting to get it to stack up properly without much luck. Anyone know what I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the part that says "Applying for a trademark registration" then when I remove

```
.menu li ul ul {
   margin: -30px 0 0 159px;
}
```

from `style.css` on line **2356** then it looks much better.

Comment: Thanks that was it! Not sure how I missed it but it was buried.

Comment: No worries. Something like firebug really helps find these little bugs.